# SharePoint 2013 follow button on webapplication is working for some users and not for others

Tags: 2013, social, follow

I have SharePoint 2013 webapplication, on which some set of users can click on follow and it allows them to follow. For other set of users, the follow doesnot do anything. Any ideas on how to look further into it. Also, i checked that the app pool identity has SPDataAccess permissions  on the content database. I dont think thats an issue, but just to clarify.

Comment: Does all users have a mysite? Or do you use self-provision for mysite?

Comment: @Christofer, we dont have mysites on that farm.

Answer (score 2):

`Follow` button on SharePoint site do have some different behavior for permissions as it is getting it from SQL directly using Application identity Pool.

There are some **PowerShell commands** to be followed after giving the permissions to allow user clicks on `Follow` button.

Please check below article which explains the same issue:
Link below
[SharePoint 2013 Following sites not working](https://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/sharepoint-2013-following-sites-not-working/)

Comment: thanks Hardik, I checked in the logs and that access error is not there.

Comment: Yes but you need to give access to PoolAccount using PowerShell Command given in link

Comment: As mentioned in the original question description, the app pool account has SPDataAccess permissions on the database.  There are some users who can click on Follow and it works for them.

Comment: That is the reason why you need to allow users to access it using the powershell script

Comment: I could not find much documentation on what changes this powershell command does internally. Do you happen to know the details of it. What levels of permissions and what items are modified when we run the powershell command $webApp.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity(“app poolId”)

Answer (score 2):

Without a personal site the end user does not have the page SharePoint will use to store the reference. The only follow that will work is for people since that is stored to the profile page.

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the StackExchange standards. Please check [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Please check the AppPool account for that web application configured Properly on SharePoint server IIS and SQL server